# New-QADUser CmdLet not adding UserPrincipalName when called in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to import users into AD using a CSV file, PowerShell, and Quest's AD CmdLets. When the users are added the UserPrincipleName is not added.

**Here is a sample CSV:**

---

FirstName,LastName,DisplayName,SamAccount,UserPrincipleName,Email

FirstA,LastA,"First Last",FLastAL.ou1,FLastAL.ou1@clients.domain.local,FLastA@outemail.com
First2A,Last2A,"First2 Last",FLast2AL.ou1,FLast2AL.ou1@clients.domain.local,FLast2A@outemail.com

---

**Here is the PowerShell snippit:**

```
$Users = Import-Csv $UserFile
foreach ($User in $Users)
{
    New-QADUser -FirstName $User.FirstName -LastName $User.LastName -DisplayName $User.DisplayName -SamAccountName $User.SamAccount -Name $User.SamAccount -UserPrincipalName $User.UserPrincipalName -ParentContainer "OU=$OUName,OU=Customers,DC=clients,DC=domain,DC=local"
}
```

Also, is this maybe a better question for ServerFault now that it is live? I feel it is definitely in a gray area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem was the fact that we are using Exchange 2007 which does not use RUS. When I used the Exchange 2007 CmdLets to do the same thing everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I checked with the latest QAD release (v1.2) and it works.